# How to Update a Unique Column in Mysql to uppercase?

Tags: mysql, sql

in mysql 5.7 :

I want to execute `UPDATE foobar SET foo = 'Bar' WHERE foo = 'bar'`

foo is unique

but I get `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Bar' for key 'foobar_foo_unique'`

what should i do ?

Comment: You seem to want to set a _lowercase_ value to _uppercase_.  Did you phrase your question title incorrectly?

Comment: Please show table schema (including role and key type of `foo` or whatever its name really is) and example data and real query (not paraphrased) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: from the error I understand that you have in your table 2 values. One that contains `Bar` and one that contains `bar`. Since foo is unique you cannot change the `bar` value to `Bar`, because `Bar` already exists.

Comment: I'm with Gabriel here. `select * from foobar where lower(foo) = 'bar'` to see what you have and then make your decision how to go about this.

Comment: my table have ```(id: int(11) primary auto_increment, name: varchar(255) unique)```. i have a row like ```(id=1, name='one')```. i run ```UPDATE projects SET name='One' WHERE name='one' ``` from code. and i use ```name``` for display in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a case-sensitive collation for the column (or perhaps for the database, but that is another matter).

You can set that when you define the table:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    foo VARCHAR(80) COLLATE utf8_bin
);
```

You can define the column to be unique in the table or create a separate index/constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    foo VARCHAR(80) COLLATE utf8_bin UNIQUE
);
```

Note that this has the happy side effect that comparisons on the column are case sensitive as well, so `where foo = 'bar'` and `where foo = 'Bar'` are different.

Comment: thanks for your answer. is it possible to use case-sensitive for UPDATE but case-insensitive for INSERT ? i want foo column to be unique rather it is uppercase or lowercase, but i want to be able to update the column's character to uppercase or lowercase...

Comment: @AliDahaghin . . . I think that you should ask a *new* question with more examples of what you do want to do and not want to do.  I think this answers the question you have asked here about uniqueness.

Comment: but this is incredibly STUPID limitation on mysql for no reason at all. Mysql SHOULD recognize when you are updating unique value on that element even if you set it to same unique value (or case modified).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a functional unique index on `foo` column such as

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foobar_foo_unique
ON foobar( (ascii(foo)) );
```

Consider this :

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foobar( foo VARCHAR(80) );

mysql> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foobar_foo_unique ON foobar( (ascii(foo)) );

mysql> INSERT INTO foobar VALUES('Bar');

mysql> INSERT INTO foobar VALUES('bar');

mysql> INSERT INTO foobar VALUES('Bar');  

Duplicate entry ....

mysql> SELECT * FROM foobar;

+------+
| foo  |
+------+
| Bar  |
| bar  |
+------+
```

If you want to have case insensitive uniqueness, convert this constraint to a standard unique index after manipulating the data properly.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b820f6b27f2e93f6e850c2137063e95d)</kbd>

***Another case :*** You may have whitespaces wrapping around(even between letters). In this case, you can think that you encounter the duplication problem. Consider this <kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f00be98cc46d67f0c03504132a50b713)</kbd> also.

Comment: hey thanks for you answer. second query can not run on version 5.7. is there any alternative ?

Comment: yes not possible for version `8.0.13 -`  @AliDahaghin , but there is a problem here, if it's a unique index, you can not insert `Bar` and `bar` at the same time. Perhaps the strings have whitespaces around them. Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f00be98cc46d67f0c03504132a50b713)

Answer (score -1):

You need to drop Unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE foobar DROP INDEX constraint_name;
```

Comment: i cant. i need to be unique... because i update it from user inputs